# Understanding interruptible cancellation with Future

Tags: java, multithreading

Java Concurrency In Practice states the following:

> A thread should be interrupted only by its owner; the owner can
>   encapsulate knowledge of the thread's interruption policy in an
>   appropriate cancellation mechanism such as shutdown method

Now let's take a look at the standard `FutureTask` implementation:

```
public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning){

    //...
    if (mayInterruptIfRunning) {
       try {
            Thread t = runner;
            if (t != null)
               t.interrupt(); //Future task may not be an owner, 
                              //yet it interrupts the running thread.
        }
    //...
    }
    //...
}
```

So, why is it safe? In case of `ThreadPoolExecutor` which `newTaskFor`'s  implemented as just

```
protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Runnable runnable, T value) {
    return new FutureTask<T>(runnable, value);
}
```

Is it safe to call something like this:

```
ExecutorService es;
Callable<Integer> task;
//init es, task
Future<Integer> ft = es.submit(task);
ft.cancel(true); //Attention at this line, thread may be interrupted
```

In case of `ThreadPoolExecutor`, we do not know about the thread interruption policy, neither does `FutureTask`. Nevertheless we interrupt it through the `FutureTask`. This is kind of perplexing...

Answer (score 2):

That quote from the book is an opinion by its author about best practices, not a statement about thread safety.  Unfortunately that book does not clearly differentiate between the two types of statements.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing claims that it's "safe". The wording is "A thread **should** be interrupted only by its owner", not **must**.

If you're calling `cancel(true)` then you should be prepared for any effects that interrupting the thread may have.

Comment: But interruptions is the mechanism designed specifically for cancelling activities. In case of `ExecutorService` we'd better of not making any assumptions about its threads interruption policy, I suppose... But if we call `cancel(true)` on a `Future` produced by the `ExecutorService` we actually do so. Otherwise, a task (even one reposnsible to interruptions) will not be "interrupted" and be allowed to finish up. Such "cancellation" seems to be completely pointless to me.

Comment: I consulted to the source of `ThreadPoolExecutor::shutdownNow()`. It's clear that it interrupts all worker threads.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's make sure the question is legitimate. Quoting from the book:

> Because each thread has its own interruption policy, you should not interrupt a thread unless you know what interruption means to that thread.

Whether `FutureTask` interrupts the underlying thread is controlled by the `mayInterruptIfRunning` parameter. Therefore `FutureTask` doesn't decide when to interrupt the thread, the *caller* decides. And the caller should have the knowledge on what is the interruption policy because she controls the execution service.

On the other hand, `ThreadPoolExecutor` doesn't really document what is the contract for interrupting its threads (except for `cancels tasks via Thread#interrupt` for `shutdownNow()`) and therefore imposes the principle violation on the caller.

I suppose that `ThreadPoolExecutor` contract could be improved in this regard. Its behavior is quite natural, though. Using the interrupt flag is the simplest way how to let the executing task know about the cancelation (otherwise an object queryable for status would have to be passed into the task, which would be cumbersome).

> So, why is it safe?

In this case, `ThreadPoolExecutor` doesn't really care whether we interrupt the thread or not. Only the tasks running inside may care and those are under the caller's control. The only two things `ThreadPoolExecutor` ensures is that the interrupted flag is cleared before a new task is started, and that threads are interrupted on shutdown (which does not violate the principle because executor owns the threads).